# Using UISearchBar in custom UITableViewCell - getting results back to TableView

Tags: ios, xcode

I must have a mental block about this!

I have a search bar as part of a custom UITableViewCell, which is part of an iBooks-like PDF bookshelf. The goal is to eliminate books on the bookshelf as letters are typed into the search bar.

My first attempt traps out the characters entered using textDidChange, which is called in the sub-classed UITableViewCell. When I get a character I send the searchText over to my TableView (where I show or hide pdfs using the searchText) using NSNotificationCenter. Works great EXCEPT the keyboard is dismissed during the notification post, and I need for it to stay up.

Possible workarounds would be

a) to prevent the keyboard from dismissing during the notification post. I have no idea if this is possible, OR 
b) somehow having the textDidChange method called from within the TableView. The delegate is assigned to the sub-classed UITableViewCell in IB, and this is where the mental block is occuring, I'm not sure if I can get the delegate moved over to the TableView, or 
c) an approach I'm overlooking.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as have a weak pointer to the viewcontroller in your tableviewcell. then you can call whatever function you want without using delegates/NSNotificationCenter. Just set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

`@property (nonatomic, weak) UIViewController *parent;`

**edit:**

To keep the keyboard active it Looks like instead of `[tableView reloadData]`

you can do :

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: That works as it should, but I'm still loosing my keyboard. After commenting out lines I find it's being dismissed by the tableView reloadData call which refreshes the bookshelf. My notification posting was just fine. So how do I keep my keyboard from being dismissed? Ah, the life.

Comment: Problem solved by not calling reLoadData and instead iterating through all of the rows and then manually updating the items in the row. Thanks, Dima, for pitching in.